# How can I upload a file(pdf or png) in my Google drive and get it's ID

Tags: c#, pdf, upload, png, maui

I am working on a project which I wish to **upload a file(s)** to my Google drive an get back it's ID or download url using **.net Maui** cross platform. I don't know where and how to start. Please can someone help.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-sdk

Answer (score -3):

I mean, usually you can go onto google drive and in the upper left hand corner click "new" and then "file upload". The id is the last part of the sharable link/address “https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/**1dyUEebJaFnWa3Z4n0BFMVAXQ7mfUH11g**, which you can get by right clicking and then clicking link. I'm not sure how to get it with .net Maui. Could you also use the file location?

Comment: This is not an answer, more like a comment. I do realize you don't have the reputation to answer yet.

Comment: Hello, this is not what he needs. He is trying to do this programatically.